# What is the main difference in between a UI KIT and a Styleguide?

Tags: visual-design, documentation, style-guide, document, document-design

We are working on documenting visual design and I wanted to know: what is the main difference between a **UI KIT** and a **styleguide**?

Is the difference between them that the **styleguide** includes design guidelines and best practices and the **UI KIT** is just showing the different components and their behaviors?

Or are both just 2 ways of documenting the same thing but with different names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the difference in between them lies in that the styleguide includes design guidelines and best practices and the UI KIT is just showing the different components and their behaviors?

Pretty much so.

A UI kit is a collection of components, either interactive (javascript) or static (photoshop), from which a user interface can be composed. [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/) provides a UI Kit.

Style guides may, but not necessary refer to a specific UI Kit (ie, an implementation). They may include advice ("do not rely on double-click as these are not intuitive on mobile"), guidelines on composition, white space, colour scheme, etc.

To give one example, Material Design is a style guide, whereas [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) is a UI Kit that adheres to the guide.

On the other hand, Apple's iOS Design Guidelines make specific references to Apple's own UI kit.

**Terminology trap** - Mind you, the word *style* with relation to UI often describes the presentation layer only, and deals less with interaction. To some "Users can swipe the switch" will not constitute a style-guide, but rather a design-guideline.

Comment: +1 for the differentiation between the _presentation_ and _behavior_ layers. I have to go through this principle constantly.